# Splitting a long file name that has no delimiter in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, file, split, format

I have this file structure -- `lastname, Firstname ID#12345.pdf`. I was able to split just the ID number by using the Right function for my ID column, but for the firstname/lastname column it includes "ID#12345". How do I split it so that in one column it is just the lastname & firstname and second column the ID number when there's no delimiter between the firstname and ID? Thanks!

Comment: If you can use `right`, you can use `mid` + `find` ^_^

Comment: You could Split on "ID#".

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're trying to achieve. It's formulas but you should be able to adapt them easily to your VBA code.

[image]

Here's the logic behind it:

1. First, all your filenames have the string "ID#" somewhere in them. You can find where exactly this string starts within the filename with the formula: `=FIND("ID#";D2)` , where D2 is your filename.
2. lastname & firstname: `=LEFT(D2;FIND("ID#";D2)-2)` means "get me all of D2's characters, starting from the left, up until the point where "ID#" starts, and remove 2 characters in order to avoid a trailing blank space"
3. ID#: `=MID(D2;FIND("ID#";D2);LEN(D2)-FIND("ID#";D2))` means "take D2, and from the point where "ID#" starts, get me all remaining characters to the right of this point" (this number of remaining characters being the length of D2 minus the starting point of "ID#")

I hope this helps!